# Mongo connection URI for statefulSet in K8s, each replica (pod) or the (headless) service?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data-mongodb

I’m little bit unsure what would the correct connection URI for my applications for the Mongodb statefulset. I have three replicas running in my cluster, each one in separate node.
Should I configure the pods OR the headless service (load balancer for the pods)?

The documentation is directing to use pods, like this (Running MongoDB on Kubernetes with StatefulSets | Kubernetes):
`mongodb://user:pwd@mongo-0.mongo,mongo-1.mongo,mongo-2.mongo:27017/dbname_?`

But I have got it working with the service as well:
`mongodb://user:pwd@mongodb-headless.svc.cluster.local:27017/dbname_?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0`

But, I don’t know what is the correct URI? The problem I’m having is that when some of the replicas goes down, for some reason, the application crashes as the database connection is lost. I think this is where the headless-service comes in picture, but no, the documentation says to configure the pods. And if I scale the replicas I need to reconfigure the URI. This does not sound so dynamic.

I’m also facing some issues with the headless service, as if it is in different namespace I cannot get the connection work with namespace defined, like:
mongodb-headless.namespace.svc.cluster.local:27017

Have I missed something?
Thank you in any advance!

EDIT: added replicaset for service/lb URI example (I had this configured...)

Answer (score 1):

I think your way of referencing the headless service will result in mongodb only using the first in the set.

Another way is using the MongoDB's [DNS seed list connection format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-dns-seedlist) together with Kubernetes' support for DNS SRV records. If you named your Service's port `mongodb`, then the following connection string ought to work:

```
mongodb+srv://user:pwd@mongodb-headless.namespace.svc.cluster.local:27017/dbname_?
```

MongoDB clients will use DNS to get a seed list on connection, which stays up to date with the actual Pods running.
Note that this [enables `tls` by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-dns-seedlist), which you probably do not want.

Comment: Thank you! Still I'm little bit confused as the service responses to ping. But should not be used as LoabBalancer. Also, I dont want to set any dns or tls for this.. But using the direct addresses to pods feels so clumsy.

Comment: tls can be turned off, and you get the DNS for free from Kubernetes' CoreDNS

Comment: ah thats true, but I dont want set any dns for this. Even thou, is it correct to use the service, should it work? Why it does not work with namespace, but works without (both response to ping from inside pod in cluster in samenamespace)?

Comment: If you just use the service name, MongoDB will only connect to the addressfirst pod that is returned from the DNS query. I am not sure it will try a different IP on reconnection. No clue about the namespace question.